# store a mysql result set as Session item for For future use

Tags: php, mysqli

can i do that in PHP:

when my website first load i want to

connect my DB execute a query and keep the result set as Session item.

than i want to be able to execute a select query on this result set.

something like this(pseudo code):

```
<?php

    include 'open_connection.php';

        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT `city`,`state_code` FROM `cities`");

        mysqli_close($con);

        session_start();

        $_SESSION['TABLE'] = $result;

        //than run a query on the result set
           $result = mysqli_query($_SESSION['TABLE'],"SELECT `city`,`state_code` FROM `cities`");

?>
```

something like asp.net disconnected architecture.

can i do it?

thank you.

Comment: Store it in an array...

Comment: If you are repeatedly executing this query, MySQL will likely be able to cache it _for you_ automatically, especially since you have no `WHERE` clause. Its performance will be excellent.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot do it in PHP **nor you have any need in this.**

Storing table contents in a session will create awfully unreliable and - worst part - incredibly multiplied "cache".

**While you don't need such a cache at all:**

A database is not something big and hulky, nor something to be afraid of. Generally speaking it's the same storage as a session. Yet it can be blazingly fast and require no cache at all if used properly. Such an issue of getting city via primary key lookup is indeed the case.

Just get your data right from DB every time you need it and don't bother with sessions at all

Answer (score -1):

I would prefer :
1) the mysql cache functions to set look at : 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache.html

2) Or if u have hughe amount to cache then i would advice php memcache http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php.
It's easy to setup.